# How can I feed new data to a deep learning script without loading libraries all over again for each sample?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've got an object detection script in Python that takes around 10 seconds to load libraries and checkpoints and then it can detect objects that I am interested in. However, I use this script over and over, on an Android app that uses this script. The script is located on a server that runs it. However every time it uses this script it takes 10 seconds to do so. How can I keep the script running and just use the detection part of the script on new data?

Comment: That depends a lot on how the server is set up; generally, you'll need to set it up so it keeps running and accepts multiple requests

Comment: I have full access to the server, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Can you describe how the script is set up on the server? What runs it, how it deals with the requests, which web framework/library, those sorts of things... (Perhaps expand the question...)